# Finding value of an algebraic expression.

Tags: problem-solving

I am given $$2x = a-\frac{1}{a} \;\text{and} \; 2y=b-\frac{1}{b} .$$
I have to find the value of $ xy +\sqrt{(x²+1)(y²+1)}.$

One way to solve this is to simply putting the value of $x$ and $y$ and get the answer, but that's a very lengthy process though lucid. But I am looking for a short cut method or some kind of tricks to solve the problem.

If anyone can visualize it, I wil be grateful for sharing.
Thank you.

Comment: If $x=\frac{1}{2}\left(a-\frac{1}{a}\right)$ then $\sqrt{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)$ for $a>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is any special trick in solving the problem. 
$$x=\frac{a}{2}-\frac{1}{2a}$$
$$y=\frac{b}{2}-\frac{1}{2b}$$
$$xy=\frac{ab}{4}-\frac{a}{4b}-\frac{b}{4a}+\frac{1}{4ab}$$
$$x^2+1 = \frac{a^2}{4}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4a^2}+1=\frac{a^2}{4}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4a^2}=(\frac{a}{2}+\frac{1}{2a})^2$$
$$y^2+1 = \frac{b^2}{4}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4b^2}+1=\frac{b^2}{4}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4b^2}=(\frac{b}{2}+\frac{1}{2b})^2$$
Putting in the above values
$$xy+\sqrt{(x^2+1)(y^2+1)}=(\frac{ab}{4}-\frac{a}{4b}-\frac{b}{4a}+\frac{1}{4ab})+\sqrt{(\frac{a}{2}+\frac{1}{2a})^2*(\frac{b}{2}+\frac{1}{2b})^2}$$
Assuming that $=\frac{a}{2}+\frac{1}{2a}>0$ and $\frac{b}{2}+\frac{1}{2b}>0$
$$=(\frac{ab}{4}-\frac{a}{4b}-\frac{b}{4a}+\frac{1}{4ab})+(\frac{a}{2}+\frac{1}{2a})*(\frac{b}{2}+\frac{1}{2b})$$
$$=(\frac{ab}{4}-\frac{a}{4b}-\frac{b}{4a}+\frac{1}{4ab})+(\frac{ab}{4}+\frac{a}{4b}+\frac{b}{4a}+\frac{1}{4ab})$$
$$=\frac{ab}{4}+\frac{1}{4ab}+\frac{ab}{4}+\frac{1}{4ab}$$
So, 
$$xy+\sqrt{(x^2+1)(y^2+1)}=(\frac{ab}{2}+\frac{1}{2ab})$$

Comment: ... assuming $a,b>0$.

Comment: @lhf, where do we need to assume a,b >0

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: Try $a = -2$ , $b = 3$

Comment: @ClarkMakmur, in $\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{a}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2a}\right)^2} = \dfrac{a}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2a}$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $t_1=a-\frac1a$ and $t_2=b-\frac1b$ and then solve

$$x=\frac{t_1}{2},y=\frac{t_2}{2}$$
Now $$xy+\sqrt{(x^2+1)(y^2+1)}$$
$$\left(\frac{t_1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{t_2}{2}\right)+\sqrt{\left(\left(\frac{t_1}{2}\right)^2+1\right)\left(\left(\frac{t_2}{2}\right)^2+1\right)}$$
$$=\frac{t_1t_2}{4}+\sqrt{\frac{t_1^2+4}{4}\cdot \frac{t_2^2+4}{4}}$$
$$=\frac{t_1t_2}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{(t_1^2+4)(t_2^2+4)}}{4}$$
and then substitute back $t_1=a-\frac1a,t_2=b-\frac1b$

Comment: There will be 4 I think !..

Comment: What do you mean by 4

Comment: In the 2nd line from last, in the denominator of the term after addition..its square root of 16, which is 4..

Comment: Ohh.. Yes I edited it now